# Minimizing the expectation over a set, wrt to the Gaussian measure

Tags: measure-theory, normal-distribution

I have recently read a proof [1] where, at the last step, the authors use an inequality which basically amounts to a lower bound on
$\int_\mathbb{R} \mathbf{1}_A(x)|x| \phi(x)dx$, where $\phi$ is the Gaussian pdf ($\phi(x)=\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$) and $A$ is a Borel set subject to $\int_\mathbb{R} \mathbf{1}_A(x)\phi(x)dx = p$. The bound they use is $p^2/2$; I was wondering if this was tight (up to a constant factor), or if one could improve this to get better than a square dependence on $p$:
$$
\min_{A\in\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}} \int_\mathbb{R} \mathbf{1}_A(x)|x| \phi(x)dx\qquad\\
\text{s.t.} \int_\mathbb{R} \mathbf{1}_A(x)\phi(x)dx = p
$$

Does anyone know if a result of this type is known? Any help or suggestion is welcome.

Clement.

[1] Theorem 4 of [Testing halfspaces In In Proc. 20th Annual Symposium on Discrete Algorithms (SODA (2009) by Kevin Matulef, Rocco A. Servedio, Ronitt Rubinfeld](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.184.761)

Comment: Have you misunderstood the argument in the paper or am I misinterpreting what you've written? The solution to the problem in your display equation is obviously negative for all $0 \leq p < 1$. For example, take $A = (-\infty,\Phi^{-1}(1-p))$ to get an upper bound on the solution.

Comment: Oh, indeed — I forgot to put an absolute value (i.e, the objective is $\int_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{1}_A(x) |x|\phi(x) dx$).

I just updated the original post.

Comment: Isn't it obvious that a symmetric interval about 0 is the minimizer ?  Mabe use the neman-pearson lemma to compare $\phi(x) , \vert x \vert \phi(x)$ (normailzed if necessary .

Comment: It seems obvious, but I didn't see a good argument for it (given the condition $\mathbb{P} A = p$, an interval centered around zero makes it having a "small" width, and makes the term $|x|$ in the objective function small as well; yet, it should be more than compensated by the fact that far from the origin the pdf brings everything down in the objective function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One looks for the minimal $E[|X|;X\in A]$ with $P[X\in A]=p$, where $X$ is standard normal. The optimal set $A$ is some $A=(-a,a)$ (see Edit below), then
$$
E[|X|;X\in A]=\frac2{\sqrt{2\pi}}(1-\mathrm e^{-a^2/2}),\qquad
P[X\in A]=\frac2{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^a\mathrm e^{-x^2/2}\mathrm dx.
$$
When $a\to0$, $E[|X|;X\in A]\sim a^2/\sqrt{2\pi}$ and $P[X\in A]\sim2a/\sqrt{2\pi}$, thus, no better lower bound than
$$
E[|X|;X\in A]\geqslant cP[X\in A]^2,\qquad c=\sqrt{2\pi}/4,
$$
can hold for every $a$. Let us prove the bound above is indeed universal.

Getting rid of irrelevant multiplicative constants, one sees that the claim holds if and every if $u(a)\geqslant0$ for every $a\geqslant0$, where
$$
u(a)=1-\mathrm e^{-a^2/2}-\frac12\left(\int_0^a\mathrm e^{-x^2/2}\mathrm dx\right)^2.
$$
Note that $u(0)=0$ and that, for every $a\geqslant0$,
$$
u'(a)=\mathrm e^{-a^2/2}\left(a-\int_0^a\mathrm e^{-x^2/2}\mathrm dx\right)\geqslant0,
$$
thus the claim holds. Finally, the optimal universal lower bound is
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} \mathbf{1}_A(x)\phi(x)dx = p\implies\int_\mathbb{R} \mathbf{1}_A(x)|x| \phi(x)dx\geqslant\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}4\,p^2.
$$
**Edit:** Assume that $P[X\in A_+]=P[0\leqslant X\leqslant a_+]$ where $A_+=A\cap(0,+\infty)$ and define $A_0=A_+\cap(0,a_+)$, $A_1=(0,a_+)\setminus A_+$ and $A_2=A_+\setminus(0,a_+)$, thus $(0,a_+)=A_0\cup A_1$, $A=A_0\cup A_2$ and $P[X\in A_1]=P[X\in A_2]$ with $A_1\subseteq(0,a_+)$ and $A_2\subseteq(a_+,+\infty)$.

Thus, $E[|X|;X\in A_1]\leqslant a_+P[X\in A_1]$ and $E[|X|;X\in A_2]\geqslant a_+P[X\in A_2]$, that is, $E[|X|;X\in A_1]\leqslant E[|X|;X\in A_2]$. Adding $E[|X|;X\in A_0]$ to both sides, one gets $E[|X|;0\leqslant X\leqslant a_+]\leqslant E[|X|;X\in A_+]$.

Likewise, replacing $A_-=A\cap(-\infty,0)$ by $(-a_-,0)$ where $P[X\in A_-]=P[-a_-\leqslant X\leqslant 0]$ yields $E[|X|;X\in A_-]\geqslant E[|X|;-a_-\leqslant X\leqslant 0]$ hence $E[|X|;X\in A]\geqslant E[|X|;-a_-\leqslant X\leqslant a_+]$ where $P[X\in A]=P[-a_-\leqslant X\leqslant a_+]$.

It remains to show that $E[|X|;-a_-\leqslant X\leqslant a_+]\geqslant E[|X|;-a\leqslant X\leqslant a]$ where $a$ is uniquely defined by the condition $P[-a_-\leqslant X\leqslant a_+]=P[-a\leqslant X\leqslant a]$. This is done as above, comparing $|X|$ on the two parts of $(-a_-,a_+)\triangle(-a,a)$.

Finally, $E[|X|;X\in A]\geqslant E[|X|;|X|\leqslant a]$, where $P[X\in A]=P[|X|\leqslant a]$.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not quite sure to understand the very first argument, which states that the minimizing set is a (zero-centered) interval. is that obvious?

Comment: See Edit. $ $ $ $

Comment: OK, I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a real proof. However it gives some ideas. First of all $x$ is linearly increasing and the density is exponentially decreasing. Due to the absolute value $|x|$ lets assume $\mathbb{R}^+$ for the moment. First we need to show for an interval $[a_1, a_2]$ if $a_1=0$ is a minimizer or not. Since $x$ is increasing and the density is decreasing at a higher rate, if there exists another interval with $a_1\neq 0$ it should either be at higher extremes or lower extremes, namely when $a_1<\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is a small number or when $a_1=k$ such that $[k, \infty]$ satisfies the area condition. If in both conditions $a_1=0$ is the minimizer than $a_1=0$ should be at least a part of the solution, namely when finitely or infinitely many number of intervals is assumed. According to some simulations that I did, when a "unique interval" is assumed $a_1=0$ is the minimizer. It is not even difficult to show it algebraically, i think.

Below is the comparision of the lower bound $p^2/2$ (magenda) with the bound obtained by $[-a_1, a_1]$ for $a_1\in\mathbb{R}^+$ (blue).

[image]

If the single interval assumption is general enough then, the blue curve is the minimizer function and the lower bound by $p^2/2$ is not tight.